# Abobe Reader print with php

Tags: php, adobe-reader

I'm having the following problem if anyone can help me I'd appreciate it. Sorry my english is not so good.

when I run this command with cmd it works perfectly

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /t "C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\Logistica\comum\EtiquetasPDF\1076-29367.pdf" "impnova"
```

but when I run this command with php it doesn't work. I'm trying this way
!

```
$imp = 'impnova';
$arq = "EtiquetasPDF\\$programa-$amostra.pdf";
$comand    = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe\" /t \"$arq\" \"$imp\"";
system($comand);            
        
echo $comand;
```

Does anybody know how to solve this ?

I tried to use php `system()` but it's not working. I expected `system()` to execute the command to print the pdf.

Comment: If this is in the context of a web application, then don't forget PHP runs on the server, so don't expect it to execute anything on the machine where you're viewing the application through your browser. (You might get round this when developing initially, because you often use the same machine for the server and browser, but it wouldn't continue to work in a real environment.)

Comment: The first thing I wanted to do is to check the content of `$comand`, but I cannot, because you post code as an image. See: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I changed the image by code

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I get:

> "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /t
> "EtiquetasPDF\1076-29367.pdf" "impnova"

Which is different from your original:

> "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /t
> "C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\Logistica\comum\EtiquetasPDF\1076-29367.pdf"
> "impnova"

To get the same as the original your code should look like this:

```
$imp = 'impnova';
$arq = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Sistema\\Logistica\\comum\\EtiquetasPDF\\$programa-$amostra.pdf";
$comand = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe\" /t \"$arq\" \"$imp\"";
```

This is no garantee that it will work, but at least it is now the same.

Comment: did not work =/

Comment: @cabril Could you respond to the comment by ADyson?

Comment: @cabril Basically, executing something using the command line of your OS is not the same as issuing the same command through PHP and your webserver. If you want to show a PDF file in a browser you simply load the PDF file, just like an HTML or PHP page.